# How to set up PPTP VPN for Windows 7 in Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to connect my VM using KVM console. The first step I did is setting vpn password in "control.softlayer.com" and set up VPN accessing in "pptpvpn.dal01.softlayer.com", but the url is not accesible. Is this right procedure to setup VPN ?

Comment: I would suggest you to visit rather this StackExchange link: http://superuser.com/ and to post this question there IMO

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The next links provide great information on VPN:

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/set-pptp-vpn-windows-7

http://www.softlayer.com/VPN-Access

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/getting-started-softlayer-vpn